# PyQt5 Button clicked event not calling connected method

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

The following is the second window in my app, the buttons in my first window all work, code is almost the same. The button in second window doesn't work both when I launch it from window 1 and when I launch it on its own.

```
    import sys
    import os
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
    from PyQt5 import uic
    import qdarkstyle
    
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    
    qtCreatorFile = "PATH TO MY .ui FILE" 
    
    Ui_error, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile) #process through pyuic
    
    class MyApp1(QMainWindow, Ui_error): #gui class
        def __init__(self,label_txt):
            #The following sets up the gui via Qt
            super(MyApp1, self).__init__()
            self.ui = Ui_error()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
            #set up callbacks
            self.ui.label.setText(label_txt)
            self.ui.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            self.ui.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            
            self.ui.b_err.clicked.connect(self.close_w) 

#This button doesn't work
# Tried to use self.close directly in clicked.connect()(which worked in window 1) but also doesn't work
    
        # Tried to use @staticmethod but didn't work
        def close_w(self):
            print('tst') # tst is not printed in console when button is clicked
            self.close()
    
    
    
    
    def errorGUI(label_txt):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
        ###
        app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5()) # Issue was caused by the stylesheet
        ###
        window = MyApp1(label_txt)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        errorGUI("Error Msg")
```

Edit:
After trying some different solutions I decided to create a new window which uses the same code with the only difference being that no text is passed to the new window. On this newly created window the button works. I assume the button problem comes from passing the string "Error Msg"(stored in variable label_txt) to the window.

Edit2:

.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>error</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="error">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>493</width>
    <height>210</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Error</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="enabled">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>41</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Placeholder Button</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="b_err">
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>16</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Close</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>493</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Edit 3:

It works when I remove the stylesheet. This is strange because all other windows/buttons work with the stylesheet

Comment: Can you please share the `ui` file also?

Comment: added in edit 2

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error: it prints the message and correctly closes the window. Are you sure you're pointing to the correct ui file path?

Comment: yes the file path is correct, the window opens and the message from label_txt is displayed, only the button is not working. Is there a different way to pass arguments(string) to the UI ?

Comment: That wouldn't change anything, the problem seems to be somewhere else, and, as I said, I cannot reproduce it: it does exactly what you say it should: show the label message, and when clicking on the button it successfully prints on the consolle and closes. Anyway: you're already subclassing from `Ui_error`, so there's no need to create a new instance, just call `self.setupUi(self)` and change all references of `self.ui.*` to `self.*`. It shouldn't be the source of the problem, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Are you running the program from an IDE? If so, can you try to run it from the consolle/prompt? Are you completely sure that you're running the program *as it is* in this question?

Comment: Yes I am running in Pycharm. All other windows are working in pycharm. I will try to run from console (just tried, same problem)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time with this btw! I will try to recreate the whole window and code and see if it works

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the stylesheet. when I comment the line:  # app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5()) the button works. my other windows also use this stylesheet and the buttons work on those with the style enabled

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot to tell you about that (I don't use that module and I commented it out). Does the button work if you try to access it using the keyboard?

Comment: Yes shortcut works with the stylesheet enabled

Comment: Then it certainly is a bug related to qdarkstyle. It seems like there's a related issue here: [Qt 5.15 MacOS - No reaction on Button-Click](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet/issues/235)

Comment: thank you very much for that link, that was my exact issue. I think downgrading PyQt5 to 5.14 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was related to the stylesheet I was using. Downgrading my PyQt5 to version 5.14 fixed the issue.
@musicamante thank you very much for your help here!